# macOS custom keyboard layout is removed each restart of the OS

Tags: keyboard, macos, input-source

I copied my custom keyboard layout into `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`. After that, I can easily choose from `System Preferences → Keyboard → Input Sources`, and it just works fine. But whenever I restart the computer, the previously added keyboard layout is deleted automatically and has to be added again The computer does not delete the files inside the `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` directory, it only deletes the entry in System Preferences.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of MacOS?

Comment: Sierra, the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a copy of your custom keyboard layout in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` directory. The `Library` directory in your Home directory is hidden by default. To enter it, click **Go** in Finder menu, press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key to reveal `Library` option.